# How to get the newest directory in Python

Tags: python, operating-system, directory

I'm looking for a method that can find the newest directory created inside another directory
The only method i have is `os.listdir()` but it shows all files and directories inside. How can I list only directories and how can I access to the attributes of the directory to find out the newest created?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import os
dirs = [d for d in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(d)]
sorted(dirs, key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(x), reverse=True)[:1]
```

**Update:**

Maybe some more explanation:

`[d for d in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(d)]`

is a list comprehension. You can read more about them [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.1/diveintopython3/html/comprehensions.html#listcomprehension)

The code does the same as

```
dirs = []
for d in os.listdir('.'):
    if os.path.isdir(d):
        dirs.append(d)
```

would do, but the list comprehension is considered more readable.

`sorted()`is a built-in function. Some examples are [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/)

The code I showed sorts all elemens within dirs by os.path.getctime(ELEMENT) in reverse.
The result is again a list. Which of course can be accessed using the `[index]` syntax and [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

Comment: Can I use listdir() instead of listdir('.')?

Comment: No, os.listdir takes a mandatory argument. The '.' is just a shortcut for "current directory" (You could also use os.curdir instead, or of course, pass the absolute/relative path to the directory you're interested in)

Comment: 'sorted(dirs, key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(x), reverse=True)[:1]' actually show a list right, so I can get just the first element by 'sorted(dirs, key=lambda x: os.path.getctime(x), reverse=True)[0]' ?

Comment: @HOAINAMNGUYEN I updated the answer. I hope that now it is more clear to you what the code does.

Comment: how to give user defined path here ?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a little function I wrote to return the name of the newest directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import glob
import operator

def findNewestDir(directory):
    os.chdir(directory)
    dirs = {}
    for dir in glob.glob('*'):
        if os.path.isdir(dir):
            dirs[dir] = os.path.getctime(dir)

    lister = sorted(dirs.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    return lister[-1][0]

print "The newest directory is", findNewestDir('/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Sites')
```

Comment: Can you explain the line lister = sorted(dirs.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)) ?

Comment: Sure! So basically, I'm just creating a dictionary where the key is the name of the directory, and the value is the creation time of the directory. Then, I sort the dictionary based on the values to find the newest directory. Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value#answer-613218

Comment: sorted() is a built-in function.  Googling for "python sorted" gets you the the docs and a few other SO questions. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted

Answer (score 5):

The following Python code should solve your problem.

```
import os
import glob
for dir in glob.glob('*'):
  if os.path.isdir(dir):
    print dir,":",os.path.getctime(dir)
```

Comment: Does this find the newest one?

Comment: @jessh Your other answer is basically a duplicate of this answer with sorting added.  It is best to edit your existing answers if you are just improving them.

Comment: Thanks! but the OP's question was how to find atributes of the directories (creation time), with the eventual intent of sorting them. Thus I answered his question. The second answer goes a step further to sort. I would prefer to keep them separate

Comment: I guess I'm just confused how this solves the problem when the first line of the problem is `I'm looking for a method that can find the newest directory created inside another directory`.

Comment: The op's question is exactly: "How can I list only directories and how can I access to the attributes of the directory to find out the newest created?"

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) and the examples in the docs for an easy way to get directories.

```
root, dirs, files = os.walk('/your/path').next()
```

Then check out [`os.path.getctime`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) which depending on your os may be creation or modification time.  If you are not already familiar with it, you will also want to read up on [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

> os.path.**getctime**(path) Return the system’s ctime which, on some systems (like Unix) is the time of the last change, and, on others (like Windows), is the creation time for path.

```
max((os.path.getctime(os.path.join(root, f)), f) for f in dirs)
```